# cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory

Tags: php, git, развертывание

Пробую настроить быстрое развёртывание php с локального пк на удалённый сервер используя git хуки вот по [этой статье](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa). Там предлагается добавить файл post-receive с содержимым

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="/home/webuser/deploy-folder"
GIT_DIR="/home/webuser/www.git"
BRANCH="master"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
    if [ "$ref" = "refs/heads/$BRANCH" ];
    then
        echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${BRANCH} branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f $BRANCH
    else
        echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

в папку hooks bare-репозитория на удалённом сервере.

Вроде всё сделал правильно, но когда делаю push на локальном - получаю:

> fatal: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory

причём если заменить в файле строчку

```
if [ "$ref" = "refs/heads/$BRANCH" ];
```

на

```
if [ "refs/heads/master" = "refs/heads/$BRANCH" ];
```

и выполнить файл в удалённой консоли, то всё разворачивается как надо и куда надо.

Так а что меняется при пуше с локального пк?

Comment: *fatal: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory*
забыли то, о чём предупредили не забыть в последней фразе [четвёртого пункта](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa#4-add-the-post-receive-hook-script)

Comment: chmod 777 post-receive делал, если вы об этом

Comment: 1. *777* — а надо было всего лишь `+x`. видимо, когда у вас спрашивают дорогу, вы ещё **дополнительно** рассказываете, где сами живёте, номер паспорта и пин--коды от банк.карт. 2. попробуйте всё-таки разобраться с проблемой. у программистов это называется «отладка». например, переименуйте скрипт и убедитесь, что сообщения нет. и далее исходя из здравого смысла.

Comment: да делал я +x, потом уже 775 и 777

Comment: та пробую, пробовал #!/bin/bash на  #!usr/bin/bash (ответ на команду whish bash) менять, формат конца строк в Unix(LF) преобразовывал

Comment: 1. `#!usr/bin/bash` — пропущен слэш. 2. начните с начала. поместите в файл одну (всего одну) строку: `echo etotest >&2`, выполните push и убедитесь, что слово `etotest` присутствует в выводе. если благополучно отработает, тогда уже добавляйте shebang.

Comment: второй пункт оказался решающей зацепкой. в итоге удалил #!/bin/bash и понеслась. так и ехать дальше или чревато?

Answer (score -1):

удалил строку

```
#!/bin/bash
```

и понеслась.

P.S. сообщите, если это решение может быть чем-то чревато - удалю ответ

Comment: вообще-то это решило мою проблему

Comment: пока никто не сказал что это решение может быть чем-то чревато - это и есть исчерпывающий  ответ на вопрос

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/496356)

Comment: как понять почему минус?

Comment: Минус просто выражает мнение конкретного участника по поводу ответ/вопроса. На одиночные минусы (без обоснования) можно не обращaть внимание.

Comment: Минус поставил я, потому что считаю ваше решение вредным. Не должно быть исполняемых файлов без указания применяемого интерпретатора. (Точно также не должно быть файлов с правами 777, правда, это другая история). Причин, из-за которых у вас не работает shebang, множество.

Comment: Для текстовых сценариев первые два байта должны быть с кодом 23 21 (соответствует `#!`). Никаких пробелов вначале, никаких UTF-BOM не допускается. Это же ограничивает возможные кодировки для содержимого файла. Не ясно, в каком окружении и на какой ОС вы пытаетесь запустить этот сценарий. Возможно, у вас не установлен Bash. Или установлен в необычное место. Не понятно, зачем вообще для этого сценария нужен Bash, ведь он не использует никакой специфичной функциональности Bash. Может быть, стоило заменить путь к интерпретатору на универсальный `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Может быть, если вы действительно хотите использовать Bash, вам бы помог трюк с `/usr/bin/env bash`. А может быть Bash у вас назван как `bash.exe`? Слишком много неизвестных параметров, чтобы утверждать наверняка. Но я уверен, существуют ещё сотни причин, о которых я не догадываюсь, но которые потенциально могут сломать у вас shebang.

Comment: ура! `#!/usr/bin/sh` помогло