# Что означает строчка в коде?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="/home/webuser/deploy-folder"
GIT_DIR="/home/webuser/www.git"
BRANCH="master"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    # only checking out the master (or whatever branch you would like to deploy)
    if [ "$ref" = "refs/heads/$BRANCH" ];
    then
        echo "Ref $ref received. Deploying ${BRANCH} branch to production..."
        git --work-tree=$TARGET --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f $BRANCH
    else
        echo "Ref $ref received. Doing nothing: only the ${BRANCH} branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

что означает `#!/bin/bash`?
без неё всё работает, насколько важна эта строчка?
P.S. к вопросу [cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150299/cannot-run-hooks-post-receive-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)#:~:text=%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%20(%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB.,%22)%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0.

Comment: без нее все работает потому что: `env | grep ^SHELL` > `SHELL=/bin/bash` или `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это
[шебанг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix))
(англ. «*shebang*»):

> Когда скрипт с шебангом выполняется как программа
> в *Unix*-подобных операционных системах, загрузчик программ
> рассматривает остаток строки после шебанга как имя файла
> программы-интерпретатора.  Загрузчик запускает эту программу и передаёт
> ей в качестве параметра имя файла скрипта с шебангом. Например, если
> полное имя файла скрипта `path/to/script` и первая строка
> этого файла:
>
> ```sh
> #!/bin/sh
> ```
>
> то загрузчик запускает на выполнение `/bin/sh` (обычно
> это *Bourne shell* или совместимый интерпретатор командной строки)
> и передаёт `path/to/script` как первый параметр.

Что касается важности, она необходима, если вы запускаете ваш скрипт
как просто `./myscript`, а если вы запускаете
`bash ./myscript`, то она выполняет исключительно
информативную функцию, указывая читающему на интерпретатор.

Comment: Последний абзац неточен. Интерпретатор смотрит в эту строку для включения режима совместимости или (пере-)запуска под правильным интерпретатором. Почитайте про shell-compatible mode in Bash, например.